# How to fix slow mysql write speed

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a school points system website that was built using codeigniter with MySQL as database. The problem is, points table as a lot of data and it's very slow to write.

It has more than 2 millions rows now. Whenever I have high number of users accessing it, it is very slow. But this did not happen when that table has less data. It is only slow for that part, but other pages loads quickly even with high number of users concurrently accessing it. I even have a dashboard that would calculate all the points and it's fast.

How do I make it run faster? I already separate my web server and MySQL server. My Database server has more resources now in terms of CPU and RAM.

When users access `/dashboard`, php will calculate all user's points. There's no problem with it.

However, when accessing `/points` and writing to the database it's very slow.

I was wondering if I would just do it like this

```
----------points table--------

|username |points_a_sum|points_b_sum|points_c_sum|

user_a    |     33     |      0     |     15

user_b    |     15     |      12    |      0
```

Instead of:

```
username|type|points|date_added

user_a | points_a | 10 | date here

user_b | points_a | 5 | date here

user_a | points_c | 15 | date here

user_a | points_a | 8 | date here

user_b | points_b | 12 | date here
```

But the problem with putting the sum directly, there's no way for my app to track when the user gets that particular points.

My app is write-heavy.

Any suggestions?

[image: Explain]

Try to get the index size using this query (https://dataedo.com/kb/query/mysql/list-of-tables-by-the-size-of-their-indexes):

```
select table_schema as database_name,
       table_name,
       round(index_length/1024/1024,2) as index_size
from information_schema.tables
where table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
      and table_schema not in ('information_schema', 'sys',
                               'performance_schema', 'mysql')
       -- and table_schema = 'your database name'
order by index_size desc;
```

[image: index]

Comment: What does `EXPLAIN` tell you?

Comment: @B001 `EXPLAIN` for writing/inserting the record?

Comment: _EXPLAIN for writing/inserting the record?_ I think yes! Why not?

Comment: Are you inserting or replacing? How large are your indexes? The issue may be that each insert/replace statement is forcing the database to rebuild the table indexes, which may be very time consuming on large tables and maybe lock subsequent insert/replace statements until the re-index is done, only to begin again with the next insert

Comment: @B001ᛦ I attached the image on my post.

Comment: Lets try to identify your bottleneck by looking at server's resource usage. Post your /etc/my.cnf settings as well as hardware that your server runs on. It is very possible that your database is not optimized for your hardware (ex: memory or IO settings). Take a look at your CPU/Memory/DiskIO usage and see what's maxing out.

Comment: @JavierLarroulet Inserting.

Comment: @Dimi my database is running on digitalocean. 2vCPU, 2GB ram. https://pastebin.com/MAePfh6c https://i.imgur.com/LI6q8JW.png

Comment: @user3569641 Depending on what you are trying to do, it is very possible that your box simply is not powerful enough to handle your requests. That being said, we can still see if we can get a much power out of it as possible. Run this script and see if it point out anything obvious. https://github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl . Additionally, see if you can find settings regarding `innodb_flush_method`, `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, `tmp_table_size`,`innodb_buffer_pool_instances`

Comment: @Dimi I run the script. Here's the result: https://pastebin.com/MgDtY1w8

Comment: Have you tried changing username and type into integers i.e user_id and type_id. From your examples it appears that you are using strings for these. Whenever you are repeating strings and using them to select rows, It immediately screams it's  a "not normalised" table design. Username comes from your users table based on user_id (as an example) And you can create a points_type table If you need to have "Points_a" etc or just simply call points_a the integer 1 etc in your code.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw I haven't tried yet. Yes you're correct, I am using strings for both columns.